# [MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)]

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a Google Map in my Xamarin forms app but am getting the above exception when navigating away from the page before the map has completed loading the current location.

This is probably the same issue previously raised but unanswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403650/xamarin-android-google-maps-exception-when-closing-page-with-map/42252932?noredirect=1#comment71664627_42252932).

From my research I believe the issue is related to leaky abstration answer given in this separate question: [MonoDroid: Error when calling constructor of custom view - TwoDScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/monodroid-error-when-calling-constructor-of-custom-view-twodscrollview/10603714#10603714)

However I do not have enough knowledge of Java or Android development to know how to resolve this issue. I am hoping that someone can explain where and how I can handle this exception when it occurs. Basically what I believe I need to achieve is catching the exception and handle it in the Droid project, but where?

These are the key exception messages that I am getting.

> Message: [NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer from native handle 0xbef7ad5c (key_handle 0xd4608e7).]
>
> Message: [MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)]
>
> Message: [Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I do not have enough knowledge of Java or Android development to know how to resolve this issue. I am hoping that someone can explain where and how I can handle this exception when it occurs.

I think the reason is when you are navigating the pages, the `Dispose` method of `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer` is called before the loading of the rest of the map. `ACW` need to create a new instance of `MapRenderer` but failed to create a new one because `MapRenderer` has no constructor method of `(IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership)`.

If you refer to [Premature Dispose() Calls](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/#Premature_Dispose_Calls) you can find following statement:

> If the subclass does contain an (IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership) constructor, then a new instance of the type will be created.

So the workaround for this exception is to create a subclass(Let's say `MyMapRenderer`) for `Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer`,which has a constructor with two arguments: `(IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership)`, and use `MyMapRenderer` for map rendering:

1. In PCL create a custom control for `Xamarin.Forms.Map.Map` and use `MyMap` instead in your project:

   ```
   public class MyMap:Map{}
   ```
2. Create a Custom `MapRenderer` in Droid project,which has a `(IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership)` contructor:

   ```
   [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyMap),typeof(MyMapRenderer))]
   namespace YourNameSpace.Droid
   {
       public class MyMapRenderer:MapRenderer
       {
           public MyMapRenderer(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) { }
       }
   }
   ```

For details about create a custom `MapRenderer`, please refer to [Custom a Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/map/).

Answer (score 0):

Updated version for answer from Elvis. Constuctor should look like as below.

```
 public MyMapRenderer(System.IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer): base(Android.App.Application.Context) { }
```

And additionally most probably you will also an empty constuctor like below. Otherwise first instance creation fails. Also for Proguard it is important.

```
  public MyMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
     }
```