# Leaky Abstraction Android Application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

EDIT: The Problem has been fixed after multiple Cleans and deleting bin folders and so on, no idea why i had to do this over 10 times.

I have extended Application class and im getting the following Error

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type
>   NetConnect.ApplicationStartup from native handle 0xbe9dcd6c
>   (key_handle 0xcfa4138).

With Respect to [MonoDroid: Error when calling constructor of custom view - TwoDScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/monodroid-error-when-calling-constructor-of-custom-view-twodscrollview/10603714#10603714) adding

```
public ApplicationStartup(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) 
            : base(handle, ownerShip)
```

did not resolve my Problem.

This is the full Code causing the problem.

```
namespace NetConnect
{
    [Application]
    public class ApplicationStartup : Application
    {

        public ApplicationStartup(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip)
            : base(handle, ownerShip)
        {

        }
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the rebuild was successful? Just delete bin/obj and rebuild. I'd add the default ctor, too.

Comment: I made a basic demo but didn't reproduce your problem. Could you please try it in a clean blank project?