# How to keep renderer with proguard in xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin.android, proguard

I am getting exception below in xamarin android. I believe that its caused by proguard but I cant figure out how to keep this renderer.

```
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.PointerRenderer from native handle 0xbef9193c (key_handle 0x2eddf05). ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for 
Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.PointerRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException:
 Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
    11-14 00:16:18.378 E/mono-rt (19328):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I tried followings. What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
-keep class com.syncfusion.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.syncfusion.** { *; }
-keep class Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.PointerRenderer** { *; }  
-keepclassmembers class Com.Syncfusion.Gauges.SfCircularGauge.PointerRenderer** { *; }
```

Comment: You could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/monodroid-error-when-calling-constructor-of-custom-view-twodscrollview/10603714#10603714

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT pretty confusing but from what I read, if I understood correctly, I am trying to create a new instance while there is already an instance. So one solution could be to dispose previous instance. according to the 3rd answer, creating a constructor could be a solution as well but this I cant do because I dont have source code. I need to ask syncfusion for fix, correct? eventually it has nothing to do with proguard, is it?

Comment: Have you tried comment out the last two lines of proguard , is  the same error ?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT yes it is the same. I added those 2 lines just because I was getting this exception.