# No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer (xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a list of image in my xaml on pcl project
when I test my app in my samsumg galaxy s5 device
I do this: I enter in the page of the list, then I press the back button on the action bar...I do it many times...then, it happens:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer from native handle 0x20e0001d (key_handle 0x42433c30).

or

> Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer from native

---

Update

I added this script:

```
using System;
using Android.Runtime;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label), typeof(LabelRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
/// <summary>
/// This renderer was added to resolve a bug that crashed the application in known case
/// Bug 36285 - Android App (Always) Crashes After Navigating Away From Page With A ScrollView In HeaderTemplate of ListView
/// <seealso cref="https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36285"/>
/// and 
/// Bug 32462 - Crash after a page disappeared if a ScrollView is in the HeaderTemplate property of a ListView
/// <seealso cref="https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32462"/>
/// </summary>
public class LabelRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer
{
    public LabelRenderer()
    { }

    public LabelRenderer(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer): base()
    { }
}
}
```

the error still here

-------------------------------------- update

Then, I changed and Now my code is:

```
using System;

using Android.Runtime;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using neoFly_Montana.Droid;
using Android.Content;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label), 
typeof(NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
public class NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer
{
    public NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
}
```

then, I can see this error frequently.

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type neoFly_Montana.Droid.NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer from native handle

the page that is running when I press the back button on the top bar and the error occurs **XAML** (PCL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.ProdutosView"          
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.LayoutScripts"
         xmlns:interface="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Interface"
         xmlns:effect="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Effects"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         BackgroundImage="prodBackground.jpg"
         x:Name="ParentHost">

<ContentPage.Content>

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Lista de produtos -->
            <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="listview_produtos" Margin="10,0,10,0" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <ListView.Header>

                <!-- Observação -->
                <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="prod_stack_obser" IsVisible="False" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="label_observ" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="20,10,0,10" />
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="lapis" Source="lapis.png" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="20"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                        <Grid Margin="20,0,20,20">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="texturaCateg.png" BackgroundColor="{Binding FundoColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="produtos_stack_color" Spacing="10">

                                <StackLayout Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage FadeAnimationForCachedImages="True" DownsampleUseDipUnits="True" DownsampleHeight="60" HeightRequest="83" WidthRequest="130" Source="{Binding imagem}" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                                            <!--<ffimageloading:CachedImage.CacheKeyFactory>
                                                <interface:CustomCacheKeyFactory/>
                                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.CacheKeyFactory>-->
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                        <!--HeightRequest="83" WidthRequest="100"-->
                                        <!--DownsampleHeight="83"-->
                                        <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Text="R$" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                                <Label Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Text="{Binding valor}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="30"/>
                                            </StackLayout>-->

                                </StackLayout>

                                        <!--nome-->
                                    <Label Text="{Binding nome}" Margin="0,10,0,10" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                                </StackLayout>
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding observacao}" Opacity="1" FontSize="Small" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor, Source={x:Reference ParentHost}}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid x:Name="prod_rl_fundo" >
                    <Grid.Margin>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                                 iOS="20,0,20,0"
                                 Android="20,10,20,10"/>
                    </Grid.Margin>
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="prod_acomp_img" Source="texturaCateg.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                        <!--Acompanhamentos-->
                    <StackLayout x:Name="stack_acompanhamentos" Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">

                        <Grid x:Name="prod_acompanhamentos_title" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.2"/>
                            <Label x:Name="produtos_acomp_title" Text="+ Dois Acompanhamentos" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}" Margin="20,20,20,20" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>

                <BoxView HeightRequest="50"></BoxView>
                </StackLayout>

            </ListView.Footer>

            </ListView>

            <!--Rodapé Grid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="rodape.png" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Grid.Row="0"/>

            <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
            <StackLayout StyleId="rodapemenu" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Margin ="5,5,5,5" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label
                   FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="Você está em:"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="White"/>

                <StackLayout.Effects>
                    <effect:SafeAreaPaddingEffect />
                </StackLayout.Effects>

                <Label FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="loja"
                   x:Name="prod_lbl_lojaprox"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

**C# of that**

```
using FFImageLoading;
using FFImageLoading.Forms;
using neoFly_Montana.Api;
using neoFly_Montana.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ProdutosView : ContentPage
{
    List<Produtos> lstProdutos = new List<Produtos>();
    Categorias categEscolhida;
    public Color FundoColor { get { return fundoColor; } }
    public Color TextColor { get { return textColor; } }
    Color fundoColor;
    Color textColor;
    string lojaProx;
    string codLoja;

    public ProdutosView(string codLoja, Object categEscolhida, object produtos, string lojaProx)
    {

        this.codLoja = codLoja;
        this.categEscolhida = new Categorias();
        this.categEscolhida = (Categorias)categEscolhida;
        lstProdutos = (List<Produtos>)produtos;
        fundoColor = Color.FromHex(this.categEscolhida.corFundo);
        textColor = Color.FromHex(this.categEscolhida.corTexto);

        this.Title = this.categEscolhida.nome;

        //TrataImagens();

        InitializeComponent();

        if (lojaProx != null)
        {
            this.lojaProx = lojaProx;
            prod_lbl_lojaprox.Text = lojaProx;
        }

        PopulaListView();

        //if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
        //{
        //    this.Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        //}
    }

    void TrataImagens()
    {
        foreach (var item in lstProdutos)
        {
            if (item.imagem != null && item.imagem.Trim() != "")
            {

                int initIndex = item.imagem.IndexOf(',');
                 string u = item.imagem.Substring(initIndex+1);
                try
                {
                    var bytes= Convert.FromBase64String(item.imagem);
                    item.imagem = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                  //  item.imagem = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var ss = e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = (ListView)sender;
        list.SelectedItem = null;
    }

    void PopulaListView()
    {

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        Grid grid_acompanhamentos = new Grid
        {
           // BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            RowSpacing = 0,
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10),
            ColumnSpacing = 0,

        };

        //CachedImage prod_acomp_img = new CachedImage
        //{
        //    Source = "texturaCateg.png",
        //    Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
        //    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(this.categEscolhida.corFundo)
        //};

        //produtos
        listview_produtos.ItemsSource = lstProdutos;

        //observação
        if (categEscolhida.observacao != null && categEscolhida.observacao.Trim() != "") {
            label_observ.Text = categEscolhida.observacao;
            prod_stack_obser.IsVisible = true;
            lapis.IsVisible = true;
        }

        //acompanhamentos
        if (categEscolhida.acompanhamentos == null || categEscolhida.acompanhamentos.Count() == 0)
        {
             stack_acompanhamentos.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //prod_acompanhamentos_title.BackgroundColor = fundoColor;
            prod_acomp_img.BackgroundColor = fundoColor;
            produtos_acomp_title.TextColor = textColor;

            foreach (var item in categEscolhida.acompanhamentos)
            {
                StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();
                stack.Margin =  new Thickness (0,10,0,10);
                stack.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                //stack.BackgroundColor = Color.Orange;
                stack.Spacing = 0;

                stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, TextColor = textColor, HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Start, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) });

                if (item.observacao != null)
                    stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.observacao, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, TextColor = textColor, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) });
                else
                    stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = " ", TextColor = textColor, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) });


                grid_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(stack, column, row);

                if (column == 0)
                {
                    column = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    column = 0;
                    row++;
                }
            }
            stack_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(grid_acompanhamentos);
            //produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(grid_acompanhamentos,
            //    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            //    {
            //        return (parent.Width / 2) - (grid_acompanhamentos.Width / 2);
            //    }),
            //    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            //    {
            //        return (parent.Height / 2) - (grid_acompanhamentos.Height / 2);
            //    })
            //);


            //produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.Children.Add(prod_acomp_img, Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
            //    return parent.X;
            //}), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
            //    return parent.Y;
            //}), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
            //    return parent.Width;
            //}), Constraint.RelativeToView(grid_acompanhamentos, (parent, sibling) => {
            //    var teste =   sibling.Height;
            //    return teste;
            //}));

            //UpdateConstraintsBasedOnWidth(produtos_rl_acompanhamentos, grid_acompanhamentos);
           // produtos_rl_acompanhamentos.RaiseChild(grid_acompanhamentos);
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateConstraintsBasedOnWidth(Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout layout, Xamarin.Forms.View view)
    {
        view.PropertyChanged += (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Width") { layout.ForceLayout(); }
        };

        view.PropertyChanged += (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Height") { layout.ForceLayout(); }
        };
    }
}
}
```

The Previous page That the page above should back to when the error occurs
**XAML** (PCL)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="neoFly_Montana.Views.CategoriasView"
         xmlns:effect="clr-namespace:neoFly_Montana.Effects"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         Title="Cardápio">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="familiaBackground.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="Fill"/>

        <!--Categ grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="9.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="gridtextura" RowSpacing="20" BindingContext="{Binding nome}" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

            <!--Rodapé Grid-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Image Source="rodape.png" 
                   Aspect="Fill"
                   Grid.Row="0"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
                <StackLayout StyleId="rodapemenu" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackLayout.Effects>
                        <effect:SafeAreaPaddingEffect />
                    </StackLayout.Effects>

                    <Label
                   FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="Você está em:"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="White"/>

                    <Label FontSize="Micro"
                   Text="loja"
                   x:Name="categorias_lbl_ljproxima"
                   Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"
                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />

                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using FFImageLoading.Forms;
using neoFly_Montana.Api;
using neoFly_Montana.Model;
using neoFly_Montana.PopUp;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CategoriasView : ContentPage
{
    ActivityIndicator indicator;

    string codigoLoja;
    List<Categorias> lstCategorias;

    List<Produtos> lstProdutos = new List<Produtos>();
    List<Acompanhamento> lstAcompanhamentos;

    Categorias categoriaEscolhida;

    string observacao;

    string codCategoria;

    string lojaProx;

    LoadingPopUp loading;

    public CategoriasView(string codigoLoja, string lojaProx, object lstCategorias)
    {
        this.codigoLoja = codigoLoja;
        this.lojaProx = lojaProx;
        //this.codigoLoja = "162";
        this.lstCategorias = (List<Categorias>)lstCategorias;
        InitializeComponent();
        categorias_lbl_ljproxima.Text = lojaProx;
        CriaTela();
    }

    void CriaLoading()
    {
        LoadingPopUp loading = new LoadingPopUp("Carregando...", Color.Brown);
        PopupNavigation.PushAsync(loading, false);
    }

    private void CriaTela()
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        gridtextura.RowSpacing = 5;
        gridtextura.ColumnSpacing = 15;

        lstCategorias = lstCategorias.OrderBy(o => o.nome).ToList();

        foreach (var item in lstCategorias)
        {
            Grid GridContent = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            var textura = new CachedImage();
            textura.Source = "texturaCateg";
            textura.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.Aspect = Aspect.Fill;

            GridContent.BindingContext = item;

            Grid boxColorView = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                //InputTransparent = true,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            boxColorView.Children.Add(new StackLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(item.corFundo), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 1);
            boxColorView.Children.Add(textura, 0, 1);

            //  boxColorView.Children.Add(new BoxView { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 0);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(boxColorView, column, row);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(GridContent, column, row);

            //Qual categoria foi escolhida?
            var CliqueCategoria = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            CliqueCategoria.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            CliqueCategoria.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                CriaLoading();
                var stacklayout = s as Grid;
                categoriaEscolhida = (Categorias)stacklayout.BindingContext;
                ChamaProdutos();
            };

            GridContent.GestureRecognizers.Add(CliqueCategoria);

            if (item.imagem != null && item.imagem != "")
            {
                int initIndex = item.imagem.IndexOf(',');
                string image = "";

                image = item.imagem.Substring(initIndex + 1);

                try
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image))), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, DownsampleHeight = 60 }, 0, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = "error.png", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, DownsampleHeight = 50, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 }, 0, 0);

                }
            }

            GridContent.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome, TextColor = Color.FromHex(item.corTexto), FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)), FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation }, 0, 1);

            if (column == 0)
            {
                column = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }

        }

    }

    async Task ChamaProdutos()
    {
        await CallingProdutosAsync();
        await CallingAcompanhamentosAsync();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.ProdutosView(codigoLoja, categoriaEscolhida, lstProdutos, lojaProx), true);

        PopupNavigation.PopAsync();

        if (lstProdutos == null)
            DisplayAlert("Ops", "Verifique sua conexão com a internet e tente novamente.", "Ok");

    }

    //carregamento de dados para a tela de produtos
    async Task CallingProdutosAsync()
    {
        lstProdutos = await Webservice.GetProdutosAsync(codigoLoja, categoriaEscolhida.idCategoria);
    }

    //este pode estar zerado
    async Task CallingAcompanhamentosAsync()
    {
        categoriaEscolhida.acompanhamentos = new List<Acompanhamento>();
        categoriaEscolhida.acompanhamentos = await Webservice.GetAcompanhamentoAsync(codigoLoja, categoriaEscolhida.idCategoria);
    }
}
}
```

-----------------update------------
Now, it seems that the label renderer error doesn't occur anymore...but the default+renderer error still here...and a null reference exception as well (I think it's related with the constructor in my label renderer code)

Comment: Did you have any custom renderer in your app?

Comment: I have, but not for label or boxview...now I added for them...I am testing now for see if they solve the problem

Comment: I also can see this "System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer from native handle 0x20e0001d (key_handle 0x42433c30)."

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/monodroid-error-when-calling-constructor-of-custom-view-twodscrollview).

Comment: I'm confuse, I read it and I don't know how I can solve this...

Comment: Your ExportRenderer call is referencing the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer obviously. Just read the first few lines and you'll see that.Try fully qualifying the LabelRenderer reference (neoFly_Montana.Droid.LabelRenderer), otherwise it seems you are creating a second Xamarin.Frons renderer for every instance. I'm commenting because I'm a fellow fly Fisher. You better let me know your app when it's released.

Answer (score 8):

You've named your class `LabelRenderer`, which already exists in the  `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` namespace.

In the assembly attribute, `typeof(LabelRenderer)` is equivalent to `typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer)`, but we need it to be `typeof(neoFly_Montana.Droid.LabelRenderer)`.

An easy way to avoid these namespace conflicts going forward is to use a unique class name, like `NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer`.

And when using Xamarin.Forms v2.5+, we need to use an overloaded Constructor, which I've added below.

#### For Xamarin.Forms v2.4 (and below)

```
using System;

using Android.Runtime;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using neoFly_Montana.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label), typeof(NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
    public class NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer
    {

    }
}
```

#### For Xamarin.Forms v2.5+

```
using System;

using Android.Runtime;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using neoFly_Montana.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label), typeof(NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer))]
namespace neoFly_Montana.Droid
{
    public class NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer
    {
        public NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms v2.5+
I changed my code as you said and now a see this error sometimes
"Unable to activate instance of type neoFly_Montana.Droid.NeoFly_MontanaLabelRenderer from native handle"

Comment: and the application stops

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste your updated code? It will be most helpful to include the complete code for the custom renderer and the Xamarin.Forms code initializing the control (both XAML and C# code-behind, if you’re using XAML)

Comment: The xaml I don't know how I should paste, because the error occurs when I press the back button on the top bar to back to previous page...I don't know if the problem is the previous page or the current page...I think is the previous page initialization...what do you think? I guess I will paste the previous page...

Comment: Include both pages so that I can reproduce the error

Comment: Delete the Dispose method from your custom renderer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167571/discussion-between-joyce-de-lanna-and-brandon-minnick).