# System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type MyProject.CancelListener from native handle

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Forms app, I am using native Android code for the platform. I want to show a `AlertDialog.Builder` and catch the event when the user taps outside of the dialog box with `SetOnCancelListener`. This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

adb.SetTitle("title");

adb.SetItems(myItems.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray(), (s, e) =>
{
    // not important code
});

var cancelled = new CancelListener();
cancelled.Cancelled += (s, e) =>
{
    // not important code
};
adb.SetCancelable(true);
adb.SetOnCancelListener(cancelled);

Dialog d = adb.Create();
d.Show();
```

My `CancelListener` class:

```
public class CancelListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnCancelListener
{
    public event EventHandler Cancelled;

    public IntPtr Handle => IntPtr.Zero;

    public CancelListener() : base()
    {

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cancelled = null;
    }

    public void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
    {
        Cancelled?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

When I tap outside of the dialog box I get the message:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type
>   MyProject.CancelListener from native handle

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593022/

Comment: It did not help, but thanks anyhow