# Xamarin.Android Application Subclass Crashes

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am newbie to Xamarin. I am trying to create application class as below code

```
[Application] 
class MyCustomApplicationClass : Application 
{ 
        public MyCustomApplicationClass (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base (handle, ownerShip) 
        { 
        } 

        public override void OnCreate () 
        { 
                base.OnCreate(); 
                // add your custom stuff e.g. here... 
        } 
}
```

It crashes app without MyCustomApplicationClass app is running perfectly fine.

Edited:-

[image: Bug here]
Thanks in advance

Comment: By `It crashes app`, could you please show the error? Please edit your question. And [here is about custom Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427981/how-to-register-my-own-application-subclass-in-xamarin-android). BTW, your code works well for me, maybe there is another error.

Comment: @JoeLv- I have edited post and added the bug screenshot

Comment: Clean, rebuild,  restart

Comment: Is it a Xamarin.forms project?

Comment: @JoeLv no Xamarin.Android Project

Comment: Already Clean,Rebuild and Restart

Comment: Xamarin.Android does not have an application class it is a concept of xamarin.forms

Comment: I don't think your there is something wrong in your `MyCustomApplicationClass`, please remove bin/obj folder and try again, you can refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Known_Issues)

Answer (score 0):

That error is often due to a conflict between **support libraries** and the version of Android sdk used.
Check if the version is the same (everything 25.x, or everything 26.x, ...), restore packages, clean everything and launch.